# Macro using Solver is hyper slow

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I need column H to be 3% and that by moving column B.
For that I used a Macro that uses Solver, but when I have 1000 lines it gets hyper slow and often it crashes.

Is it possible to combine Solver with Arrays to get hyper fast results?

The code I used is:

```
Sub SolverMacro()
    
    Dim LR As Integer
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To LR
        SolverReset
        SolverOk SetCell:="$H$" & i, MaxMinVal:="3", ValueOf:=0.03, ByChange:="$B$" & i, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverSolve True
    Next
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to combine multiple Solver operations and improve speed could be to use the fact that you can specify a multi-cell range to the `ByChange` argument (eg. `ByChange:=Range("C2:C8")`).

This way you could supply all the values in the C column as input instead of one cell at a time. Then for the `SetCell`, you would have to create a cell that is dependant on all the values in column H. For instance, you could have the following (array function) calculation:

```
=SUM((H2:H8-0.03)^2)
```

Basically, this is the quadratic [loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function) that gets bigger when the distance from the required value (0.03) increases. To get the desired result, you can ask the Solver to minimize it or ask the Solver to set its value to zero.

Note however, that after testing for larger ranges, it seems that the Solver has a limit of 200 cells as input range. This means that if you have more, you'd have split them into 200 rows batches.